# AddSubView on UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I try to add `UIView` on `UIViewController`:

```
AppDelegate *md = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[md.tab.view addSubview:view];
```

And i noticed that the UIView not start from :
[image]

I create the TabBarController on The MainWindow.Xib

Comment: just place the view with y = 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct behaviour, assuming you're adding your view to the `UITabBarViewController`'s view. A tab bar controller takes up the entire screen - the tabs at the bottom, and the tab content above that.

It sounds as if you want to add a view to the *tab bar* rather than the view controller. To do this you should use the `tabBar` property of your tab bar controller.

Comment: There is no other way to fix it? because the problem is that i use Ads in my app, and when i set the ads ,i need to insert the rootviewcontroller, and i init for this the tabcontroller and then the popup ad won't show like it need to shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AppDelegate *md = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, IS_I5?519:431, 150, 44)]; // Change y position
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[md.tab.view addSubview:view];
```