# How to put UIView in UITabBarController (Like Apple Music App)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to replicate the mini player on the Apple Music app. It looks like this:

[image: Mini Player Apple Music]

Right now I have a `UITabBarController` plus two `UIViewControllers`. Now I wanted to put a `UIView` in the `TabBarController` (for the mini player) so its always on top of the content of the `ViewControllers` that are loaded in the tabs. But it seems to be impossible to add any UI elements into a `tabBarController`.
So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I create a View that is right above the tabbar and is above all other views in the tabs?

EDIT: the suggested duplicate doesn't answer my question. Is it not possible to add Views to the `TabBarController` via `Storyboards`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AddSubView on UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187613/addsubview-on-uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your EDITed question: No, it is not possible to add Views to the TabBarController via Storyboards. That's not how TabBarControllers work.

Options:

- Follow the direction in the 'possible duplicate' link posted and add
  subviews via code, or
- Subclass UITabBarController and add subviews via
  code, or
- Write your own "tab bar controller" and, using IBDesignable and
  IBInspectable, provide for adding subviews in Interface Builder

You could probably find inspiration / ideas by searching the web for "custom UITabBarController"

Comment: Thanks for you input. I ended up just doing it in code. I made a xib for the mini player and added it to the tabBarController via code.

Answer (score 4):

**To answer your question:** No, you cannot add a view to the `UITabBarController` via storyboard.

Though you can have a look at `LNPopupController`. https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController

It's a wonderful library which will enable you to do what you want to accomplish.